# Apex Error No such column 'ParentCampaign' on entity 'Campaign'

Tags: soql, campaign

I'm trying to make an SOQL query to the CampaignMember table, which checks both the Campaign of the CampaignMember and the ParentCampaign of that CampaignMember.

The Campaign.ParentId works, but the Campaign.ParentCampaign doesn't, telling me it doesn't exist, despite it [being in the list of available fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaign.htm) on the Campaign object.

My SOQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT Contact.Account.MauticID__c, Campaign.MtcSID__c, Campaign.ParentId, Campaign.ParentCampaign FROM CampaignMember WHERE (CampaignId IN :cids OR (Campaign.ParentId IN :cids AND Campaign.ParentCampaign.MtcSID__c != NULL)) AND Contact.Account.MauticID__c != NULL AND Contact.Account.MtcPossibleSpamsniffer__c = FALSE AND Contact.Account.NoEmails__c = FALSE AND MtcInMautic__c = FALSE
```

which gives the error "No such column 'ParentCampaign' on entity 'Campaign'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

I've also tried Campaign.Parent (as that is the field's name according to the Salesforce setup page), but that gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't query relationships. You can either query Id or fields from relationship.

Try to use

```
SELECT Campaign.ParentId FROM CampaignMember
```

or

```
SELECT Campaign.Parent.Id FROM CampaignMember
```

or

```
 SELECT Campaign.Parent.<StandardOrCustomFieldName> FROM CampaignMember
```

Comment: D'oh! I actually realized the mistake almost immediately after posting. Thanks, it works fine now!
(But I'm still a little confused as to why the documentation refers to the reference field as `ParentCampaign`. Maybe it's outdated.

Comment: The documentation describe SOAP API which might have different signature or names than the standard Apex SOQL.

Comment: Ah... But where is the documentation for the Apex-available fields for the Campaign object then? I've been searching around but couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform seems to copy information from SOAP API Guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaign.htm, we should report somewhere that Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform is incorrect. There is no such relation name as ParentCampaign, it is just Parent.

Comment: I have reported using Feedback bottom link. Not sure if they would change the documentation though